# Combining Navigation Rail with Drawer

Tags: android, material-design

I am currently improving the tablet version of my app and was looking to add a "Navigation Rail" similar to the "Reply" app from the Material Design, you can see an example of the rail in this link: https://material.io/design/material-studies/reply.html#product-architecture and video example here: https://material.io/components/navigation-rail#behavior

Direct link to the video: https://kstatic.googleusercontent.com/files/7774e2fd23c0eee7d85dd9bd5015944191b6c0878da3539b269a39475f3c0aaaf87fa558802d4d8b95c916a69f8d99fda844dcdb19c646a1fbe8fd1f81f45556

The idea is to have the rail on the left side of the UI and on click it will expand into a Navigation Drawer, I have been trying different things for over a week now, implementing Navigation Rail or Drawer individually isn't a problem, combining both of them is a bit tricky.

Any ideas on how to achieve it?

Comment: Hey, have you got any breakthroughs?

Comment: @Renjith I have not, we decided to let it go eventually, if you have some direction I would love to see it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement the exact same behavior you can directly have a look at the source code of the "Flutter gallery" app, and especially [the "reply" application](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/tree/main/lib/studies/reply) package.

I think what your are looking for is in their use of the NavigationRail widget in [this file.](https://github.com/flutter/gallery/blob/main/lib/studies/reply/adaptive_nav.dart)

Comment: Unfortunately I am looking for an answer in native Android, either Java or Kotlin

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I didn't see the tags on your question...